# Including header files in C

Tags: c, include, header-files

I am working on a project in which If I could include a header file at runtime, it would save some programming effort. I google'd about it, but all in vain. My question is :
Can we include header files in a C program at runtime ?
If yes, how?
If not, why?

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve? A header file is an input to the compiler, and you don't have the compiler at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, no. Header files are brought in by the *compiler* to satisfy symbols needed during compilation.

If you simply want values *unrelated* to compilation, you can always put them in a configuration file which is read at runtime.

Other possible solutions are command line arguments or environment variables but, since you're discussing putting them into a file, the first option is probably the best.

Answer (score 2):

In C the source files are only read compile-time, so the answer to your question is **not**. Runtime there is only the executable binary, which has nothing to do with your source code headers.

Answer (score 0):

No header files can't be added at run-time as,
The four stages for a C program to become an executable are the following:

```
1) Pre-processing
2) Compilation
3) Assembly
4) Linking
```

and Pre-processing is the very first stage through which a source code passes. In this stage the following tasks are done:

```
1) Macro substitution
2) Comments are stripped off
3) **Expansion of the included files**
```

and observation from intermediate file shows that we can get by passing argument to gcc as  gcc -Wall -save-temps hello.c -o hello :

```
1) All the macros are expanded in the preprocessing stage.
2) All the comments are stripped off.
3) The third observation is that beside the line ‘#include’ is missing and instead of that we see whole lot of code in its place. So its safe to conclude that stdio.h and header files has been expanded and literally included in our source file.
```

and then compilation of code takes place ..

So including header files before compilation is needed.